# How to Find the List of Runtime Variables in IDE

Tags: java, qtp, java-bytecode-asm

I want to retrieve all the variables and the different values at different intervals in Programming IDE. For example, consider QTP is a testing tool and I have a script which was scripted with 10 variables. During run time the value so often changes and I want to document the variable values whenever it changes. How to access those generically instead of writing the values on own when we know that it changes? Are there any possibilities?

Comment: Debuggers will show you this information.

Comment: @byxor: Yes debugger will show the information of the know variable and you need to keep debugging point in the all the places  if you want the values of all. I want to construct a mechanism where during the execution of a exciting script or new one it will automatically logs the value at different intervals for all the variables. Suggestion towards that is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need a debug information. Java API for this: [JPDA](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/index.html)